# How to add a MediaType to the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter instead of the RestTemplate

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-4, zimbra

My question is very similar to [How to change MediaType for MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter in OAuth2RestTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854855/how-to-change-mediatype-for-mappingjacksonhttpmessageconverter-in-oauth2resttemp) but different in many ways.

I am using Spring 4 with SprintBoot. I want to use `RestTemplate` to query a Zimbra web services. The web service returns "JSON SOAP". It's really just JSON response in a format of a SOAP message.

Unfortunately, the response comes back as `text/javascript; charset=utf-8` so the Message Converter fails as it does not find any converter for that media type.

How do I tell `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` to consider this content type the same as regular JSON?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much looking, I found the solution to this problem. When one calls `new RestTemplate ()`, a whole bunch of default `HttpMessageConverter`s are created and loaded. This does not use any Spring beans.

So if like me you want to let the `RestTemplate` get configured with all its default but just add the necessary content type to the list, you can do the following:

```
  RestTemplate myRest = new RestTemplate ();
  for (HttpMessageConverter<?> myConverter : myRest.getMessageConverters ()) {
     if (myConverter instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
        List<MediaType> myMediaTypes = new ArrayList<MediaType> ();
        myMediaTypes.addAll (myConverter.getSupportedMediaTypes ());
        myMediaTypes.add (MediaType.parseMediaType ("text/javascript; charset=utf-8"));
        ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) myConverter).setSupportedMediaTypes (myMediaTypes);
     }
  }
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but it did work! Thanks!  I think using RestTemplate as a bean, and injecting a new converter with text/javascript might be the way to go.

Comment: Potentially dangerous for CSRF if you start adding content types which are not real JSON